# I'll stay in Paris for a few days: Why does Duolingo say "Je resterai quelques jours à Paris" right but "Je resterai à Paris quelques jours" is wrong?

Tags: adverbes, compléments

Was doing a Duolingo exercise which asked to translate:

> I will stay in Paris for a few days.

So I wrote:

> Je resterai à Paris quelques jours.

This was marked wrong. The correct answer was:

> Je resterai quelques jours à Paris.

Why?

Comment: Both sound fine to my native speaker's ears

Comment: I don't know whether Duolingo simply has one "correct" answer stored or whether multiple options are allowed. Either way, it is not a human and jot AI, so the cases like one in the OP often happen and in many languages (in my experience.) On occasion I was directly told by a team that the course is not designed for native speakers and does not include all the possible options that one can come up with.

Comment: This is why I only give Duolingo exercises to my beginner classes. With even intermediate competence you begin to outpace the program and be held back by it. Also, it's embarrassing to do an exercise like this in front of the students, get told you're wrong, and have to explain why you're smarter than Duolingo 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> À Paris quelques jours je resterai !

Blame duolinguo...

In your sentence, there are three indivisible units:

- *je resterai*
- *à Paris*
- *quelques jours*

You can't break them apart (e.g. <s>*Je **à Paris** resterai*</s>) but you are free to order them the way you like. Some orders will sound perfectly natural like both of duolingo and your answers while some others might sound strange, archaic, literary or poetic, but none is technically ungrammatical.

Here is a famous dialog precisely related to word ordering in French (**bold** mine):

> MONSIEUR JOURDAIN : *Non, vous dis-je, je ne veux que ces seules paroles-là dans le billet ; mais tournées à la mode ; bien arrangées comme il faut. Je vous prie de me dire un peu, pour voir, les diverses manières dont on les peut mettre.*
>
> MAÎTRE DE PHILOSOPHIE : *On les peut mettre premièrement comme vous avez dit : « **Belle Marquise, vos beaux yeux me font mourir d’amour** ». Ou bien : « **D’amour mourir me font, belle Marquise, vos beaux yeux** ». Ou bien : « **Vos yeux beaux d’amour me font, belle Marquise, mourir** ». Ou bien : « **Mourir vos beaux yeux, belle Marquise, d’amour me font** ». Ou bien : « **Me font vos yeux beaux mourir, belle Marquise, d’amour** ».*
>
> MONSIEUR JOURDAIN : *Mais de toutes ces façons-là, laquelle est la meilleure ?*
>
> MAÎTRE DE PHILOSOPHIE : *Celle que vous avez dite : « **Belle Marquise, vos beaux yeux me font mourir d’amour** ».*
>
> MONSIEUR JOURDAIN : *Cependant je n’ai point étudié, et j’ai fait cela tout du premier coup. Je vous remercie de tout mon cœur, et vous prie de venir demain de bonne heure.*
>
> Molière, *[Le Bourgeois gentilhomme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bourgeois_gentilhomme)*, Acte II, scène 4, 1670

---

Comment: Yoda, sort de ce corps !

Comment: Il manque _À Paris je resterai quelques jours_ et on aura fait le tour !