# Y-a-t-il des règles générales pour placer les compléments de temps ?

Tags: indications-de-temps, indications-de-lieu, compléments

Y-a-t-il des règles générales pour placer les compléments dans une phrase ? La position de certains compléments semble très bien définie, par exemple :

- Les jours de semaine souvent apparaissent en début de la phrase, avant le sujet, comme

> *Lundi matin*, Sonia et moi, avons écrit le compte rendu de ces jours à présenter au Conseil et sur lequel continuer ensuite à travailler.
> *Lundi et mardi prochains*, les parlements nationaux se réuniront à Helsinki à l'occasion de la réunion de la COSAC

- Les expressions temporelles introduites par *il y a* apparaissent normalement à la fin de la phrase :

> Je suis arrivé à Paris *il y a cinq ans*.
> Vous avez déménagé *il y a deux mois*.

Il y a quelques exemples avec d'autres expressions [ici](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/fle/les-expressions-temporelles-ca-fait-il-y-a-...-que-pendant-il-y-a-48.php) (comme *ça fait ... que*, *il y a... que*.)

Par contre, hormis quelques situations bien définies, la position semble au choix... ou selon l'intuition du locuteur (ce qui est assez dangereux pour ceux qui apprennent la langue.) Par exemple, la phrase proposée dans [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/52147/9870):

> Je resterai *quelques jours* à Paris.

vs.

> Je resterai à Paris *quelques jours*.

Même si les deux phrases sont parfaitement compréhensibles, y-a-t-il une règle générale voulant que le complément de temps doit précéder le complément de lieu ou vice versa ? Même si une telle règle n'est pas codifiée en grammaire, est-ce que l'une des deux options est employée plus fréquemment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le traitement de la [place du complément de phrase](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/complement.html#210) dans la grammaire de JM Kalmbach donne une réponse d'ensemble à cette question. Voici ce qui est dit en ce début de texte.

> Place du com­plé­ment de phra­se
>
> Le com­plé­ment de phra­se (CdP) peut en principe se placer li­bre­ment dans la phra­se. Il se place notamment  assez sou­vent en tête de phra­se :
>
> • Dans notre maison, il y a deux étages.
> • Avec tout leur équipement, ils sont partis pour la montagne.
> • J’ai fait le trajet de nuit Paris-Vienne en train. Dans le wa­gon-lit, il y avait mê­me une douche, quel luxe !
>
> Mais il peut se placer pra­ti­que­ment n’importe où dans la phra­se :
>
> (a) **Au début de la séance**, le professeur avait pré­sen­té le con­te­nu de son cours aux étudiants. 
> (b) Le professeur, **au début de la séance**, avait pré­sen­té le con­te­nu de son cours aux étudiants.
> (c) Le professeur avait pré­sen­té le con­te­nu de son cours aux étudiants **au début de la séance**.
>
> On voit dans l’ex­em­ple (b) qu’on peut mê­me met­tre le com­plé­ment de phra­se entre le su­jet et le ver­be (ce n’est ce­pen­dant pas pos­si­ble quand le su­jet est un pro­nom faible). On pourrait aus­si très facilement placer le com­plé­ment de phra­se entre l’au­xi­liai­re et le par­ti­ci­pe : *le professeur avait, au début de la séance, pré­sen­té*….

Le détail de toutes les possibilités particulières pourrait résulter en beaucoup de texte. Je vais donner quelques cas en rapport avec la question du PO.

> Je suis arrivé à Paris il y a cinq ans.

Dans le contexte de la narration la place du complément n'a pas d'importance particulière. Dans le contexte d'une question ce n'est plus pareil, elle est imposée.

- Quand êtes-vous arrivé à Paris ?
  Je suis arrivé à Paris il y a cinq ans.
  Il y a cinq ans.
  <s>Il y a cinq ans je suis arrivé à Paris.</s>

> Vous avez déménagé il y a deux mois.

Cet arrangement est le seul idiomatique lorsque on considère l'intervalle de temps comme centre de la discussion (il est ici question  de sa longueur).

• Vous avez déménagé il y a deux mois, ne me dites pas que vous n'avez pas encore eu le temps de faire le rangement, vous n'avez pratiquement aucune possessions.

*ou*

• Il y a deux mois *que* vous avez déménagé, ne me dites pas que vous n'avez pas encore eu le temps de faire le rangement, vous n'avez pratiquement aucune possessions.

*Cet arrangement est idiomatique lorsque on conteste le moment.*

• Il y a deux mois vous avez déménagé et vous nous dites aussi qu'alors, vous étiez en vacance… c'est bien « deux mois » que vous avez mentionné aussi dans ce contexte ; comment est-ce que vous faites votre compte ?

*ou*

• Vous avez déménagé, il y a deux mois,  et vous nous dites qu'alors, vous étiez en vacance… c'est bien « deux mois » que vous avez mentionné aussi dans ce contexte ; comment est-ce que vous faites votre compte ?

> Je resterai quelques jours à Paris.
>
> vs.
>
> Je resterai à Paris quelques jours.

On peut vérifier que « [Je resterai quelques jours à](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22resterai%20quelques%20jours%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) » se dit aussi.

Je n'ai pas à l'esprit de nuances particulières concernant ce cas-ci.

Dans la même référence on trouve ceci.

> Le fait de changer la place du com­plé­ment de phra­se ne se fait ce­pen­dant pas selon l’humeur du lo­cu­teur : la posi­tion du com­plé­ment de phra­se a une influence sur le sens de la phra­se […]. La place du com­plé­ment de phra­se dépend sou­vent de l’informa­tion qu’on veut don­ner. Com­pa­rer :
>
> • Nous partons en voyage dans deux semaines.
> • Dans deux semaines, nous par­tons en voyage.
>
> La première phra­se répond à la ques­tion *Quand partez-vous en voyage ?*, tandis que la deuxième répond à la ques­tion *Qu’est-ce que vous faites dans deux semaines ?*.

Cependant, il est possible de répondre à la seconde question comme ceci.

• Nous partons en voyage… dans deux semaines. (*ajout après coup dans le sens d'assurer l'interlocuteur qu'il s'agit bien du moment mentionné*)

Comment: Merci. Le fait que *le com­plé­ment de phra­se peut se placer li­bre­ment dans la phra­se* est un élément très important de mon point de vue. Ca peut paraître évident aux locuteurs natifs de certaines langues (comme français ou russe), mais j'avais appris de mon expérience que ça peut aussi faire une grosse différence et/ou présenter une grosse difficulté pour l'apprentissage (comme en allemand, par exemple.)

Comment: @RogerVadim En quoi trouvez vous cela important ? Voudriez-vous dire que le fait d'associer des interprétations différentes à des placements différents apporte de la versatilité à la langue, ou plutôt serait-ce important parce que le placement « libre » libère du soucis de faire des erreurs ? C'est vraiment libre mais seulement dans certains cas,, et dans d'autres ce ne l'est pas du tout (comme expliqué dans ma réponse).

Comment: Les element clé d'un langue cible ne sont pas forcement les même comme dans la langue maternelle (ou l'autre langue qu'on avait appris). L'exemple que j'avais déjà donné et l'allemand, ou [le placement de complements et assez reglamenté](https://www.gymglish.com/fr/wunderbla/grammaire-allemande/lordre-de-base-des-complements-dans-une-phrase-la-regle-tekamolo) et peut change le sense de la phrase. Certain choix typique de français, comme le complement de temps placé  avant le sujet, ne sont pas du tout grammatique en allemand.

Comment: Comme une exemple inverse (ou le français est assez rigide) je peux donner les difficultés rencontrées par les russophones apprenants l'anglais ou le français: à ceux-ci il faut expliquer explicitement que le verbe se place après le sujet et avant l'objet - autrement la phrase n'est pas compréhensible à une francophone, même si elle est ligique en russe (qui à l'ordre de mots libre.) Tout ça est lié à [l'interlangue](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlangue_(linguistique))